# Paypal payment method in Laravel

Tags: paypal, laravel-5, payment

I just think about that i have to integrate a payment method for my site.My site is developed in laravel.That's why i am looking for a way to add paypal integration.[My site](http://automatekode.com/) is there you can visit.

Answer (score 0):

**Follow Bellow Few Step:**
**1)Install Laravel Application**
**2)Database Configuration**
**3)Install Required Packages**
**4)configuration paypal.php file** 
**5)create route** 
**6)create controller** 
**7)create view file**

**Step 1 : Install Laravel Application**
we are going from scratch, So we require to get fresh Laravel application using bellow command, So open your terminal OR command prompt and run bellow command:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
```

**Step 2 : Database Configuration**
In this step, we require to make database configuration, you have to add
 following details on your .env file.
**1.Database Username**
**1.Database Password**
**1.Database Name**

In .env file also available host and port details, you can configure all details as in your system, So you can put like as bellow:
**.env**

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

**Step 3 : Install Required Packages**
We have required following 2 packages for integrate paypal payment in our laravel application.
add following two package in your composer.json file.

```
"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.4",
"paypal/rest-api-sdk-php": "*",
```

then after run following command in your terminal

```
php artisan vendore:publlish
```

after run this command, then after automatic create paypal.php file in your **config/paypal.php** path.

Step 4 : Configuration paypal.php file

```
&lt;?php

return array(
/** set your paypal credential **/
'client_id' =>'paypal client_id',
'secret' => 'paypal secret ID',
/**
* SDK configuration 
*/
'settings' => array(
    /**
    * Available option 'sandbox' or 'live'
    */
    'mode' => 'sandbox',
    /**
    * Specify the max request time in seconds
    */
    'http.ConnectionTimeOut' => 1000,
    /**
    * Whether want to log to a file
    */
    'log.LogEnabled' => true,
    /**
    * Specify the file that want to write on
    */
    'log.FileName' => storage_path() . '/logs/paypal.log',
    /**
    * Available option 'FINE', 'INFO', 'WARN' or 'ERROR'
    *
    * Logging is most verbose in the 'FINE' level and decreases as you
    * proceed towards ERROR
    */
    'log.LogLevel' => 'FINE'
    ),
);
```

**Step 5: Create Route**
In this is step we need to create route for paypal payment. so open your **routes/web.php** file and add following route.
**routes/web.php**

```
Route::get('paywithpaypal', array('as' => 'addmoney.paywithpaypal','uses' => 'AddMoneyController@payWithPaypal',));
Route::post('paypal', array('as' => 'addmoney.paypal','uses' => 'AddMoneyController@postPaymentWithpaypal',));
Route::get('paypal', array('as' => 'payment.status','uses' => 'AddMoneyController@getPaymentStatus',));
```

**Step 6: Create Controller**
In this point, now we should create new controller as AddMoneyController in this path **app/Http/Controllers/AddMoneyController.php**. this controller will manage layout and payment post request, So run bellow command for generate new controller:

```
php artisan make:controller AddMoneyController
```

Ok, now put bellow content in controller file:
**app/Http/Controllers/AddMoneyController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Validator;
use URL;
use Session;
use Redirect;
use Input;

/** All Paypal Details class **/
use PayPal\Rest\ApiContext;
use PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential;
use PayPal\Api\Amount;
use PayPal\Api\Details;
use PayPal\Api\Item;
use PayPal\Api\ItemList;
use PayPal\Api\Payer;
use PayPal\Api\Payment;
use PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls;
use PayPal\Api\ExecutePayment;
use PayPal\Api\PaymentExecution;
use PayPal\Api\Transaction;

class AddMoneyController extends HomeController
{

    private $_api_context;
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        /** setup PayPal api context **/
        $paypal_conf = \Config::get('paypal');
        $this->_api_context = new ApiContext(new OAuthTokenCredential($paypal_conf['client_id'], $paypal_conf['secret']));
        $this->_api_context->setConfig($paypal_conf['settings']);
    }



    /**
     * Show the application paywith paypalpage.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function payWithPaypal()
    {
        return view('paywithpaypal');
    }

    /**
     * Store a details of payment with paypal.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function postPaymentWithpaypal(Request $request)
    {
        $payer = new Payer();
        $payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

        $item_1 = new Item();

        $item_1->setName('Item 1') /** item name **/
            ->setCurrency('USD')
            ->setQuantity(1)
            ->setPrice($request->get('amount')); /** unit price **/

        $item_list = new ItemList();
        $item_list->setItems(array($item_1));

        $amount = new Amount();
        $amount->setCurrency('USD')
            ->setTotal($request->get('amount'));

        $transaction = new Transaction();
        $transaction->setAmount($amount)
            ->setItemList($item_list)
            ->setDescription('Your transaction description');

        $redirect_urls = new RedirectUrls();
        $redirect_urls->setReturnUrl(URL::route('payment.status')) /** Specify return URL **/
            ->setCancelUrl(URL::route('payment.status'));

        $payment = new Payment();
        $payment->setIntent('Sale')
            ->setPayer($payer)
            ->setRedirectUrls($redirect_urls)
            ->setTransactions(array($transaction));
            /** dd($payment->create($this->_api_context));exit; **/
        try {
            $payment->create($this->_api_context);
        } catch (\PayPal\Exception\PPConnectionException $ex) {
            if (\Config::get('app.debug')) {
                \Session::put('error','Connection timeout');
                return Redirect::route('addmoney.paywithpaypal');
                /** echo "Exception: " . $ex->getMessage() . PHP_EOL; **/
                /** $err_data = json_decode($ex->getData(), true); **/
                /** exit; **/
            } else {
                \Session::put('error','Some error occur, sorry for inconvenient');
                return Redirect::route('addmoney.paywithpaypal');
                /** die('Some error occur, sorry for inconvenient'); **/
            }
        }

        foreach($payment->getLinks() as $link) {
            if($link->getRel() == 'approval_url') {
                $redirect_url = $link->getHref();
                break;
            }
        }

        /** add payment ID to session **/
        Session::put('paypal_payment_id', $payment->getId());

        if(isset($redirect_url)) {
            /** redirect to paypal **/
            return Redirect::away($redirect_url);
        }

        \Session::put('error','Unknown error occurred');
        return Redirect::route('addmoney.paywithpaypal');
    }

    public function getPaymentStatus()
    {
        /** Get the payment ID before session clear **/
        $payment_id = Session::get('paypal_payment_id');
        /** clear the session payment ID **/
        Session::forget('paypal_payment_id');
        if (empty(Input::get('PayerID')) || empty(Input::get('token'))) {
            \Session::put('error','Payment failed');
            return Redirect::route('addmoney.paywithpaypal');
        }
        $payment = Payment::get($payment_id, $this->_api_context);
        /** PaymentExecution object includes information necessary **/
        /** to execute a PayPal account payment. **/
        /** The payer_id is added to the request query parameters **/
        /** when the user is redirected from paypal back to your site **/
        $execution = new PaymentExecution();
        $execution->setPayerId(Input::get('PayerID'));
        /**Execute the payment **/
        $result = $payment->execute($execution, $this->_api_context);
        /** dd($result);exit; /** DEBUG RESULT, remove it later **/
        if ($result->getState() == 'approved') { 

            /** it's all right **/
            /** Here Write your database logic like that insert record or value in database if you want **/

            \Session::put('success','Payment success');
            return Redirect::route('addmoney.paywithpaypal');
        }
        \Session::put('error','Payment failed');

        return Redirect::route('addmoney.paywithpaypal');
    }
  }
```

**Step 7: Create View**
In Last step, let's create paywithpaypal.blade.php(resources/views/paywithpaypal.blade.php) for layout and we will write design code here and also form for pay amount by paypal, So put following code:
**resources/views/paywithpaypal.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                @if ($message = Session::get('success'))
                <div class="custom-alerts alert alert-success fade in">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true"></button>
                    {!! $message !!}
                </div>
                <?php Session::forget('success');?>
                @endif

                @if ($message = Session::get('error'))
                <div class="custom-alerts alert alert-danger fade in">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true"></button>
                    {!! $message !!}
                </div>
                <?php Session::forget('error');?>
                @endif
                <div class="panel-heading">Paywith Paypal</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" id="payment-form" role="form" action="{!! URL::route('addmoney.paypal') !!}" >
                        {{ csrf_field() }}

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('amount') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="amount" class="col-md-4 control-label">Amount</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="amount" type="text" class="form-control" name="amount" value="{{ old('amount') }}" autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('amount'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('amount') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Paywith Paypal
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Now we are ready to run our example so run bellow command ro quick run:

```
php artisan serve
```

Now you can open bellow URL on your browser:

```
http://localhost:8000/paywithpaypal
```

please visit this toturials link..

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ly2xm_NM46g